# EOS light history node

Tags: nodeos, history

I have tried setting up the EOS light history node from the instructions mentioned at 'https://steemit.com/eos/@greymass/introducing-light-history-nodes-for-eos' , build getting successful, but after trying to install getting message 'try building first'. Finally I am able to install using eos_install.sh script provided.

Please suggest how to start the EOS node?

Comment: What kind of information are you interested in?  That post is 2 years old and there are many API options available (Hyperion, dfuse, state_history), the first 2 have free API options. You can ask Aaron Cox in the main EOS dev channel as well https://t.me/joinchat/DQRZHEPktgcLlyfbl-bDuQ

Comment: for details on those instructions you followed please ask the question on the telegram eosio dev channel here https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1
the greymass representatives are always there ready to help also this is a duplicate of
https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/eos-light-history-node-setup/5897#5897